# how to get rid of mailicious redirect

Tags: redirects, security, malware

I'm in charge of a Wordpress site (currently offline) that's affected by a malicious redirect, i.e. going to that address redirects to a phishing site (curiously though it only happens when getting there through a search engine, I didn't see the redirect when typing in the address directly).

We only know the redirect has been there for about two months. I installed the Cerber anti malware plugin in Wordpress and observed hundreds of login attempts on the account of a former admin, which I then removed. Removing all content associated with his account basically stripped the page of all customized content.
I have an older backup of the web files that is assumed to be clean. However, we have no backup of the database that's older than a week.
It seems for now the only two options are
a) a full re-install plus restoration of all content,
or
b) restoring the hoster's recent backup (web files and database), getting back to the site's infected state.

Question:
If we were to go with b), how good is the chance to remove the infection and get back to clean state while keeping all content online?

Comment: There's no way of knowing the answer to your question without knowing specifically what is causing the redirect.  There are so many possible reasons, including that the problem is not in the WP content.  You say you don't get redirected when typing the address in directly.  The browser you test from, is it on same network?  Using a different proxy?  Have you checked your DNS config?  Have you looked at the network traffic to see if the browsers being redirected received a 301 or is the redirect coming from somewhere else?

Comment: If you mean, is my test browser on the same network as the webserver, then no, I'm managing it from home, and my webiste is on a shared vhost.
If by DNS config you mean that the domain is pointing to the correct IP: yes it is.
How to monitor the network traffic to look for a 301?
The anti malware scanner found a couple hundred "critical problems" but I don't know what to do with that if it says "executable code found" in a .php file - like, duh.
I'm suspecting the redirect is hidden in the database or one of the web files, but if it's coming from someplace else, how would I find out?

Comment: You can enable your Developer Tools in your browser.  Usually it's F12 (I use FF).  You can look in the Network traffic section for your 301. You might also try also try something like tools.pingdom.com and look at the "waterfall". The waterfall might show you how far through our webpage you get before being redirected, giving you a clue about which file contains the malware.  Keep in mind that content in WP is stored in the database, not in files.  Having copies of your files (copied via browser) obviously would help you if you have to start all over with a clean database.

Comment: So to seriously diagnose the problem, I'd have had to do b), but I found that could extract some of the old content for re-use and went for a clean re-install, taking more security precautions from the start. I learned that you can't just run a vanilla Wordpress instance and think that it's gonna be fine.